# How to add custom request preprocessing to hippo?

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters, hippocms

It is need to add custom request preprocessing logic to hippo application. If we look at java ee - there is a [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which can be used to grab information from request.

Does hippo offers something similar? Or is it possible to register custom java ee [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) in hippo appilcation?

**P.S.** There is a sample with [Pipeline Mapping Configuration](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/request-handling/hst-2-request-processing.html), but they did not mentioned any custom pipiline adding.
Hippo version is 7.

**Updated**

It is needed to recognize a visitor from requests. E.g. query string if got from request check whether session contains this param already, if no store it into session, and save information about site visitor to db async (also cookies are updated after saving).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to inject custom valves into the processing pipeline, see [this page](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/hst-spring/hst-orderable-valve-support.html) for an example.

But, can you update your question with a bit more about context about what you want to achieve functionally? Hippo (and especially the HST) has many built-in features for all sorts of request processing. So developing a custom valve might be overkill. Also, which release of Hippo are you using? 7.9.8 or another version?